# What am I doing wrong while trying to create a GRPC for web from my proto definition using protoc command in JavaScript?

Tags: grpc, protoc

I'm trying to create a JavaScript from my proto definition.

I'm using this command:

```
protoc \
--proto_path=./grpc \
--grpc-web_out=mode=grpcwebtext:./lib/gerado/grpc/js/ \
--fatal_warnings interface.proto
```

But nothing is generated. And no one message of error is show.
What I'm doing wrong?

I have been tried all kind of approach to solve this.

> P.S.: Only now i notice that if in my .proto file there is at least
> one service, than no output is generated to javascript.

Comment: I'm surprised you don't see errors because your command can't work as you've shown. If you include a `--proto_path=${SOMETHING}` then you **must** include e.g. `${SOMETHING}/interface.proto` otherwise `protoc` will (correctly) inform you that it is "too dumb to figure out when two paths are equivalent".

Comment: @DazWilkin with this configuration, I can gerenate Dart, and Node.js code. I only can't generate javascript for browsers.

Answer (score 2):

`interface.proto`:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

service X {
    rpc Y(Z) returns (Z);
}

message Z {
};
```

With binaries from the releases added to `{PATH}`:

- [`protoc-gen-grpc-web` 1.4.2](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/releases/tag/1.4.2)
- [`protobuf-javascript` v3.21.2](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf-javascript/releases/tag/v3.21.2)

And without `--js_out`:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:${PWD} \
${PWD}/interface.proto
```

Generates `interface_grpc_web_pb.js` as expected.

With `--js_out`:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--js_out=import_style=commonjs:${PWD} \
--grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:${PWD} \
${PWD}/interface.proto
```

Additionally generates `interface_pb.js`

Comment: Thank you.
Your example made me to note what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm pleased to learn that it helped.